# Bash script Perf Stat to CSV

Tags: bash, csv, pipe, perf

i am trying to save the PERF results in a CSV File. 
I need this data with a different number of threads:

```
   345,622,750      cache-misses                                                
    22,368,050      tx-start                                                    
    22,362,278      tx-commit                                                   
         5,772      tx-abort                                                    
            94      tx-conflict                                                 
            59      tx-capacity                                                 

  16.641667950 seconds time elapsed
```

in a table like this:

cache misses | tx-start | tx-commit | tx-abort | tx-conflict | tx-capacity | runtime

(result thread =1)

(result thread =2)

(result thread =4)

(result thread =8)

....

```
Code:
file=/dir/out.csv
i=0
threads=1

while [ $i -le 7 ]; do
perf stat -e cache-misses,tx-start,tx-commit,tx-abort,tx-conflict,tx-capacity ./${benchmark}.rtm -v32-r4096 -n10 -p40 -i2 -e8 -s1 -t$threads &>> ${file}
let threads=threads*2
let i=i+1

done
```

i got a mixed output of my benchmark and perf and i just need the perf data (stats and runtime) for the csv file.

```
Scalable Data Generator - genScalData() beginning execution...
Finished generating edges
No. of intra-clique edges - 22043427
No. of inter-clique edges - 890631
Total no. of edges        - 22934058

Time taken for Scalable Data Generation is  6.383911 sec.


    genScalData() completed execution.

Kernel 1 - computeGraph() beginning execution...

    computeGraph() completed execution.

Time taken for kernel 1 is 10.230289 sec.

Time taken for all is 16.614200 sec.


 Performance counter stats for './ssca2.rtm -s20 -i1.0 -u1.0 -l3 -p3 -t1':

       345,622,750      cache-misses           //ONLY THIS                                     
        22,368,050      tx-start               //ONLY THIS                                    
        22,362,278      tx-commit              //ONLY THIS                                     
             5,772      tx-abort               //ONLY THIS                                      
                94      tx-conflict            //ONLY THIS                                       
                59      tx-capacity            //ONLY THIS                                     

      16.641667950 seconds time elapsed        //ONLY THIS
```

Comment: `perf stat -x ',' ./a.out` ? Even a short scanning for csv of documentation of perf stat shows -x option...

Comment: where to put stat -x ',' ./a.out? perf stat -e cache-misses,tx-start,tx-commit,tx-abort,tx-conflict,tx-capacity -x ',' ./a.out ./${benchmark}.rtm -v32-r4096 -n10 -p40 -i2 -e8 -s1 -t$threads AND perf stat -e cache-misses,tx-start,tx-commit,tx-abort,tx-conflict,tx-capacity ./${benchmark}.rtm -v32-r4096 -n10 -p40 -i2 -e8 -s1 -t$threads -x ',' ./a.out does not work

Comment: `perf stat -x ',' -e 'blablabla,fields,fields' ./executable.. -v32 -i2 -e8 -r <other options to your executeble>`. Pass `-x ','` ro perf not to executable. Also `./a.out` is just an example executable name I used.

Comment: how to pipe that into a csv file, i just get the output with the seprator on the terminal 56505917;;cache-misses;20516222168;100.00;;
43002273;;tx-start;20516222168;100.00;;
42990144;;tx-commit;20516222168;100.00;;
12129;;tx-abort;20516222168;100.00;;
10073;;tx-conflict;20516222168;100.00;; and the output of my executeable. If i use perf stat -x ';' ./a.out -e cache-misses,tx-start,tx-commit,tx-abort,tx-conflict,tx-capacity ./${benchmark}.rtm -v32-r4096 -n10 -p40 -i2 -e8 -s1 -t$threads it does not find my executeable

Comment: csv file __is__ a comma (or another delimeter) separated file. The output is a csv file. As for [how to pipe it to a file in bash](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20how%20to%20pipe%20that%20a%20file) you can find that in google

Comment: thank you for your answers >> file.csv i know, but i still got the output of my executeable

Comment: Then maybe it is a good time to read [man perf-stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html) and use `record [-o file]` to record the stats to a file rather then output them to standard output. `perf stat -x ',' -e blabla,bla record -o file.csv ./executable -executable-options`

Comment: this genereates a file with wired data  hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½@0-17ï¿½ï¿½TC&@18-35(@software@uncore_imc_5#@uncore_cbox_15@uncore_cbox_8!@uncore_cbox_13@uncore_r2pcie
hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½@0-17ï¿½ï¿½TC&@18-35(@software@uncore_imc_5#@uncore_cbox_15@uncore_cbox_8!@uncore_cbox_13@uncore_r2pcie

Comment: Maybe without record? Just `perf stat -o file.csv` ?

Comment: thank you kamil, this works fine, but just for one iteration, i am looping the number of threads for my executeable and the result contains only the last iteration because the old result was overwritten.